# OpenRewrite: What is a "quark"?

Tags: openrewrite

When I run a recipe I see messages like this one:

`Parsing as quark .../my_big_cucumber.feature as its size 12Mb exceeds size threshold 10Mb`

What does this message mean? I also see the message for json files. Clearly the files are too big, but what are the implications of this?

Comment: Probably refers to Quarkus, https://quarkus.io/

Comment: It's not related to Quarkus in any way; answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "quark" is what we call files that we could not parse or manipulate with OpenRewrite; we provide you with this message such that you know any changes you might have expected in these files will not be applied.

In this case it's because the files are too large; but it can also be because it's a file type we do not (yet) recognize.

Feature files are text, and should normally be parsed as such, but I must say I've never seen a feature file that large before, even as a contributor to cucumber-jvm. Would you want to make changes to your feature files through OpenRewrite? Or if not then it's safe to ignore this message for now.

Comment: It is a big feature file. The project has a few of that size or larger. I would love to have a way to "rewrite" Gherkin files.

Comment: Feel free to describe your use case on a feature request here, and then we'll have a look at what changes are necessary both in terms of feature recipes, and supporting large files in OpenRewrite.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-migration/issues